# Datamapper: Deleting all records that have no relations

Tags: ruby, postgresql, datamapper

How would I go about deleting all records from a table that have no relation in datamapper? The tables in question are a Post and Tag table (in a many-to-many relationship) and I would like to delete all Posts that have no tags. For some reason when trying `Post.all(:tags => nil)`, this error appears:

```
DataObjects::SyntaxError: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = character varying
LINE 1: ...amp", "comment_count" FROM "posts" WHERE NOT("id" IN (SELECT...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
 (code: 52461700, sql state: 42883, query: SELECT "id", "timestamp", "source_network", "source_post_id", "source_user_id", "source_link", "img_full_url", "img_thumb_url", "approved", "review_timestamp", "comment_count" FROM "posts" WHERE NOT("id" IN (SELECT "tags"."name" FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "post_tags" ON "tags"."name" = "post_tags"."tag_name" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "post_tags"."post_id" = "posts"."id")) ORDER BY "id", uri: postgres:tom@localhost/hash_tagging?scheme=postgres&user=tom&password=&host=localhost&port=&path=/hash_tagging&query=&fragment=&adapter=postgres)
  from /Users/tom/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:147:in `execute_reader'
  from /Users/tom/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:147:in `block in read'
  from /Users/tom/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:276:in `with_connection'
  from /Users/tom/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:141:in `read'
  from /Users/tom/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/repository.rb:162:in `read'
  from /Users/tom/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/collection.rb:1117:in `lazy_load'
  from /Users/tom/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/lazy_array.rb:409:in `each'
  from /Users/tom/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/collection.rb:504:in `each'
  from /Users/tom/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/collection.rb:976:in `map'
  from /Users/tom/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/collection.rb:976:in `inspect'
  from /Users/tom/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. The tag table only has one column (the name, which is a key), and the relation is the auto-generated one by datamapper

Answer (score 1):

Change `NOT("id" IN` to `"id" NOT IN`

```
   DELETE FROM posts WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tags)
```

Comment: That still comes up with the same error pointing to the `IN` bit